# Call the dialog from Intent

Tags: android

Is it possible to call a dialog from Intent. I have two Activity RegisterActivity and AuthenticActivity and I implemented custom dialog on RegisterActivity but I also need same dialog on AuthenticActivity. So how can we get that dialog on AuthenticActivity. Can we get that from Intent, Please suggest me? I don't want to write code on both Activity.

Comment: Create a Custom Dialog Class and use that wherever u want.

Comment: You should consider using events

Comment: IMO, you should have one activity for both registration and authentication (LoginActivity), but that would be two different fragments. It's better to create another class for your dialog (extend DialogFragment) and show the dialog whenever you want with something like: new MyDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), MyDialogFragment.TAG)

Answer (score 1):

Have a BaseActivity in which you can common code, in your case have a 
public method. Both your RegisterActivity and AuthenticActivity should extend BaseActivity.

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

```
public void displayCommonDialog() {

   View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_account_dialog, null);
```

........
........

```
}
```

}

public class RegisterActivity extends BaseActivity{

........
.........
........

//To call the dialog
   displayCommonDialog();

}

You can use interface or EventBus library to trigger event/ have callback listeners to capture the click events in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

short awnser: use a BroadcastReceiver.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_EXECUTE_EXAMPLE_TEST)) {
      //Do whatever you want
  }
}
```

Check it out for yourself [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Add it on manifest and then you can receive the intent in your activities ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make static constant method like,

```
public static void showDialog(PASS_REQUIRED_PARAMS){
// do your stuff
}
```

To call this method you just need to write,

```
CLASS_NAME.showDialog(PASS_REQUIRED_PARAMS)
```